# Fixed column in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to make one of column in my layout fixed. Unfortunately when I make it fixed it doesn't fit to parent div width. Is there any way to achieve that.

Html:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 100px;">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Content</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.col-sm-9 { background: red; color: white; }
.col-sm-3 { background: blue; color: white; position: fixed; right: 0; }
```

Here is jsfiddle that demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/F5VmF/2/.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/dxWdM/1/

Comment: `position:fixed` means your col-sm-3 is now relative to the viewport so it's 25% width is no,longer 25% of the container but of the viewport

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your position fixed from your `.col-sm-3` div, and insert another div inside it with a position absolute. And whenever you scroll the page, you will change the top position of that div. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/5v9JR/embedded/result/) is the example. And here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/5v9JR/).

Comment: I hope that there is any way to do that without JavaScript

Comment: If you check http://getbootstrap.com/components/, they have a fixed right column but i think they use javascript also for that, you should check that.

Comment: I have updated your sample and it looks like content in col-sm-3 has wrong width: http://jsfiddle.net/xxrkD/4/

Comment: Well just add width: 100% on it and it's all done. I've updated the jsfiddle from the answer.